# Hide a column in the grid which is a layout element in WPF using BooleanToVisibility converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind  the visibility property of a GRID column using a Boolean to Visibility Converter.  The Grid is always visible even though the bool value is false. Please help me fix this issue. The code works perfectly fine for a datagrid but not for a Grid .Here is the code.

```
 <Window x:Class="MyApp.FirstWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel" 
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;  assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:MyApp.Framework.Converter"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4" 
    DataContext="{Binding MyAppViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    MinHeight="530" MinWidth="275" Height="530" Width="275" Title="{Binding Title}"  >

 <Window.Resources>     
    <y:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
  <Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="gridTest"
       DataContext="{Binding GridDataContext, Mode=TwoWay}"   
       Visibility="{Binding GridVisibility, Mode= TwoWay, Converter=   {StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label >Date</Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1">Time</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Time}"/>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

BoolToVisibilityconverter.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Globalization;

  namespace MyApp.Framework.Converter
  {
   public sealed class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object     parameter,         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return ((bool)value == true) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Inverse")
        {
            return ((bool)value == true) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

MyAppViewModel.cs

```
public class MyAppViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

     private bool _isGridVisible = false;

     private bool _isLabelVisible = false;
     private MyItem _gridDataContext;
     public MyItem GridDataContext
    {
        get { return _gridDataContext; }
        set
        {
            _gridDataContext = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GridDataContext");
        }
    }

     public bool IsLabelVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLabelVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isLabelVisible == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isLabelVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLabelVisible");
        }
    }
    public bool GridVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _isGridVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isGridVisible == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isGridVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GridVisibility");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>-
    /// Initializes a new instance of the AppViewModel class.
    /// </summary>      
    public AppViewModel()
    {
        _gridDataContext = new MyItem();
        //other code.
    }
  private void UpdateMyItem()
    {
        try
        {
            bool wasSet = false;

            if (test== null)
            {
                SetVisible(false, "No feature selected.");
            }
            else
            {
                SetVisible(false, String.Format("No test         
                information  selected for my item {0}.",    
                 test.name.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')));
            }
         }
   private void SetVisible(bool wasSet, string msg)
    {

        //under construction
        if (wasSet )
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
            {
                GridVisibility = true;
                IsLabelVisible = false;

            });
        }
        else if (!wasSet )            
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
            {
                GridVisibility = false;
                IsLabelVisible = true;
                LabelContent = msg;

            });
        }
    }

}
```

}

I haven't found any answers appropriate for what I am doing. The blogs have answers to hiding/showing Datagrid columns and not Grid layout element. Is this possible? Is my XAML for the Visibility property of the Grid OK? Thanks for your help.

Solution: MyAppViewModel.cs

```
      private void SetVisible(bool wasSet, string msg)
      {  
         if (wasSet)
         {
             Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
             {
                 GridDataContext.GridVisibility = true;
                IsLabelVisible = false;                   
             });
         }
         else if (!wasSet)            
        {
             Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DynamicInvoke(delegate()
             {
                 GridDataContext.GridVisibility = false;           

                 IsLabelVisible = true;
                 LabelContent = msg;                   
             });
         }
     }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of DataContext="{Binding GridDataContext, Mode=TwoWay}" ?

Comment: GridDatacontext is a property that stores an object that populates the Grid . I have edited the viewmodel to show  how I am using it.

Comment: Since you assign the DataContext of Grid as GridDatacontext, it will not be able to use GridVisibility which is in MyAppViewModel. Hence it will not change the visibility.

Comment: There's already a BooleanToVisibilityConverter in the framework.  Use that one.  Next, grab Snoop and dig into your UI.  Check the binding, see if it has any errors.

Comment: Yes, I have snoop installed, when I scroll down to visibility property for GridTest in snoop, Snoop  errors out as object reference as null and stops debugging.I have an error log that did not capture the null reference error.

Comment: @Ayyapan, makes sense, I will try something else.

Comment: @Ayyapan, for further clarification , GridDatContext is a property in myAppViewModel.

Comment: I resolved the issue with the clue @Ayyapan provided, All I had to do was add a public bool property GridVisibility in the MyItem class, and use this one in the SetVisibile function . I have edited the answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @ Ayyappan Subramanian it's due to different DataContexts.

Window's context is the `MyAppViewModel` which has `GridVisibility` property implemented but Grid's context is value of `GridDataContext` property within `MyAppViewModel` (typeof `MyItem`).

So you need to point to the right DataContext when binding `Visibility`

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" 
      Grid.Column="1"
      Name="gridTest"
      DataContext="{Binding GridDataContext}"
      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.GridVisibility, 
                   Mode=TwoWay, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                   Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Or if this is not an option, change the implementation of `MyItem` to include  given property.

```
public class MyItem : ViewModelBase
{
    // Current implementation goes here...

    // GridVisibility implementation
    private bool _isGridVisible = false;
    public bool GridVisibility
    {
        get { return _isGridVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isGridVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the same solution I came up with, I added the solution . However I would like to give you credit because you have taken time and came up with the right solution.